# What do you do when a professor saying that he has not received a link for recommendation?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I'm applying to a university for a Ph.D., which requires 2 letters of recommendation. I asked a professor to submit this letter 8 days before the deadline (and provided him the necessary e-mail link within hours). It is now due 2 days before the deadline. This professor still hasn't submitted his letter (my application is otherwise finished). I've asked him, and he tells me that he has not received any email for a recommendation letter submission. I told him the deadline is due in 2 days he said that he needs at least 1-2 weeks to send it.

Should I wait for him, hoping that he turns in his letter after the deadline? What should I do with him? He was my master advisor and I wrote 3 papers for him, all good journals.

**Update**: It has been more than a week since I asked that person to fill out the letter. He agreed to do that, but after I submitted his name, he just says he has not received an email yet. Even when you ask him to send the letter directly he just does not respond. I need two-three weeks. The letter is very simple, it looks like a questionnaire can be filled in 10 minutes. I asked the university to resend but god knows if he really puts an effort to search through his emails to find it. There is a lack of respect, and this prof does not bother himself to search his email.

Comment: Why do you phrase it as "keeps saying" if he seemingly only has said it once and provided you with his timeline in response - it is not like he is ghosting you...

Comment: I asked the university to send him the link. Still, he said that he has not received it.

Comment: I guess you've double checked that you provided the right address, and asked the professor to check their spam folder?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you ask him earlier (several weeks ago) to write this letter, and inform him of the deadline when you did so?

Comment: It has been more than a week now, why does not submit his part? How much would it take for a prof to submit a recommendation?

Comment: @nikki -- can you please address the questions we have already asked? How long ago did he first agree to write this letter? How long ago did you ask the university to send the link?

Comment: 8 days ago he agreed, the link was sent a few hours later after he agreed.

Comment: I totally understand why you are worried and stressed by this deadline, but it is totally reasonable to need more time to write a solid letter. Your estimates of how much effort it takes are completely incorrect and bordering on offensive. If someone actually took 10 minutes to fill out this form it would be clear to the admissions committee it was done in 10 minutes and that could possibly harm your application worse than having no letter.

Comment: "_the link was sent a few hours later after he agreed._" How do you know the link was sent to the professor's e-mail address without accessing the professor's e-mail?

Comment: University send me this email saying that links were sent.

Answer (score 2):

Two days is an extremely short notice. That your masters' advisor is unwilling to act upon it is completely understandable. He has provided you with sufficient information in response; your options are to **find someone else** (good luck doing that, given the rush) **or ask the submission committee for a deadline extension**.

Finally, your question does not mention any reasons for giving such short notice. If you have extraordinary circumstances, it is reasonable to ask everyone involved for some extra help. Otherwise, learn from this transgression: it is already despicable to not value time of your subordinates to make them adjust everything to your schedule, and it is absolutely crazy to expect that from people who are not your subordinates.

In this specific case, you needed your advisor to write a LOR (a reasonable expectation), but entirely disregarded accommodating them sufficiently. I am sorry, but that is just unacceptable. Things happen, but you have forced yourself into calling for a big favor from what normally is very routine, and your went into it without realizing you were asking for that much.

**Even if something appears trifle to you, never ever assume others will do it on a whim and give them some breathing space.**

So, address that mentality and ask someone else.

P.S. Given you rely on having asked the university to send the link to him, did you also assume they have done it the same very day? If so, this is also unreasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do not think you understand my question.

Comment: My read is that OP asked for the letter with plenty of time (and the professor agreed to write), but for some reason (probably a spam filter), the e-mail with the link to the portal where such letters are submitted never arrived. So, I don't think there's any indication that OP's "mentality" is fundamentally problematic.

Comment: @cag51 I could not interpret "it was due in 2 days" any other way with how the question was posed, sorry. Maybe I rushed responding, but I believe some clarifications about the timeline are due in that case. If your reading is correct, it would help to know if OP asked the university to send the link X time before the deadline, got to the professor Y time before the deadline and found out they have not received it. In some cases, the inconvenience caused would be a good reason to push your cause, but I just could not read the post that way.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Agree the question is far from clear -- hopefully OP will clarify.

Comment: @Lodinn, you did not understand my question and the answer you provided is not addressing my question. It has been more than a week since I ask that person to fill out the letter. He agreed to do that, but after submission, he just says he has not received an email yet. Even when you ask him to send the letter directly he just does not respond. There is a lack of respect, and this prof does not bother himself to search his email. Maybe in your country, profs are following the same procedure, what is important is that you should respect your student and her/his future.

Comment: @nikki I have provided options to consider; not sure why would you say the answer is not addressing your question - these options are even in bold and quite hard to miss. Your attitude is still greatly irksome - why would your advisor respect you if you apparently do not respect their time? They are not responsible for your future, you are. One is also not entitled to a LOR just by being someone's student. They probably do have good will, but that does not make them a doormat. You catch more flies with honey; making requests instead of demands goes a long way...

Answer (score 0):

By the tone and the wording in this question, I'd say there is a huge tension between you and this professor -- although he was your advisor.

You feel like he ignores you, and too lazy to do a simple search through his emails, and you, in return, don't give the benefit of doubt as to him being extremely busy for a couple of months.

In these type of situations, I personally believe that it is not beneficial for the person who asks for a recommendation to push things. It is always a possibility that the professor is choosing not to write a letter instead of writing a really bad one which will make sure you get an immidiate rejection.

All considered, I think your best course of action would be to ask another person.

Also, a pro tip: It is always a good idea to ask people whether it is OK to put their names as a reference **even before** starting to submit applications. This has a lot of benefits, the most common one being the referees drafing up a template for you so that they can change a few sentences/words for every other application you submit.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, before even submitting his name, I asked whether it is possible to put you as a referee and he said yes.

Comment: @nikki nowhere in the question you mention that you got the professor's confirmation to put his name as a referee